# Manage Rails credentials on lib installed with Yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, algolia

I have installed Algolia places in rails with yarn. I am trying to add the api key to rails credentials.

I am importing into application.js with a places.js file:

```
'use strict';
import places from 'places.js';
import placesAutocompleteDataset from 'places.js/autocompleteDataset';

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var placesAutocomplete = places({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxx',
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxxx',
        container: document.querySelector('#user_street_address'),
        templates: {
          value: function(suggestion) {
            return suggestion.name;
          }
        }
      }).configure({
        type: 'address'
      });
      placesAutocomplete.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
        document.querySelector('#user_state').value = e.suggestion.administrative || '';
        document.querySelector('#user_city').value = e.suggestion.city || '';
        document.querySelector('#user_zipcode').value = e.suggestion.postcode || '';
        document.querySelector('#user_country').value = e.suggestion.country || '';
      });

  });
```

I have tried to add a initializers in /config/initializers/algoliasearch.rb

```
AlgoliaSearch.configuration = {
  application_id:  Rails.application.credentials.algolia[:applicationId],
  api_key:  Rails.application.credentials.algolia[:apiKey],

  # uncomment to use backend pagination
  # pagination_backend: :will_paginate

}
```

but I receive a  uninitialized constant error

How can I secure the credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use ERB interpolation if you want to use Rails encrypted secrets.

But its really a very pointless endeavor as the credentials are passed to the client in cleartext. There are no secrets in the browser.

Instead you can just pass them as [ENV variables to webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/).

Comment: Thanks,  I will need to setup a web pack.config file.  will update there.

Comment: I don't think this is completely pointless. For example for a Stripe integration you have a private key and a public key. I want to share the public key in the JS, but of course keep the private key encrypted. IMO it's a lot cleaner to just store them both together as credentials rather than having the secret key in the credentials file and the public key in an environment variable